# if operation in tensorflow

Tags: python, if-statement, tensorflow

I'd like to use if operation in tensorflow, as I've learned tf.cond()should be used here. While I'm confused about what if i'd like to use only if operation instead else operation. For example:

```
a = tf.Constant(10)
b = tf.Constant(5)
for i in range(5):
  tmp = tf.greater_equal(a,b)
  result = tf.cond(tmp, lambda:tf.constant(i), None)
  if result is not None:
    return i
```

as above, I want to do nothing in else operation, while tf.cond() ask there has to be a value to return.Hope someone can provide some help.

Comment: The code you pasted makes me think that you don't fully understand the tensorflow computation model. I would suggest reading up on that a bit or start using eager execution - https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager. You can use normal python control flow there.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the actual question, if you understand the graph execution model of Tensorflow, you will see that after the conditional, your execution flow must converge again. Meaning that the operations you perform on the result of `tf.cond` must be technically possible independent of the branch taken in `tf.cond`. If they are dependent, they should be part of the `tf.cond` itself.

For the convergence to happen, you have to return same looking tensors from both branches. If you "don't want to do anything" in the `else` branch, you can just return some zero tensors or some reshaped input from there. What exactly makes sense, depends on your exact use case.